# Using a custom class within another custom class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, oop

I have a custom class Manager in Xcode. This class spawns several instances of class Player on a timer, so every tick of the timer it will make a new instance. I would like to pass the instance of Manager to each instance of Player through Players init method:

`-(id)initWithMngr:(UIImage *)image andManager:(Manager *)mngr`

Here I get the error "expected a type." with or without the asterisk. The Manager class is in the same project and everything but I don't understand how to do this. I am very new to Objective C, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add either `#import "Manager.h"` or `@class Manager;` to your file, where interface of `Player` class is defined - possibly, "Player.h". (Here I suppose that your `Manager` class interface is defined in "Manager.h" file and `Player` - in "Player.h".)

If you will choose variant with `@class Manager`, don't forget to add `#import "Manager.h"` to your `Player`'s implementation file (suppose, "Player.m").